# How to use gtk to draw graphics？

Tags: linux, gtk, gtk3, gnome

I want to use gtk to draw a picture. This pictures contains two circles and a line which connects the two circles.So how to complete it?

Comment: You can use [`GtkDrawingArea`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkDrawingArea.html)

Comment: Can you show me C codes for this？There are no examples for this on web.

Comment: The [chapter on custom drawing](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s05.html) in the GTK tutorial has some C code to show you how to do it. Note that you can just use cairo-related functions in general to do drawing, with some basic examples being mentioned [here](http://zetcode.com/gfx/cairo/basicdrawing/).